# Problem tracing arrays, understanding arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm having difficulties understanding how this array works. I have done a System.out.print and realise that the new arrays are printed as follows {4,2,3,0,2} , {4,2,3,0,3}, {4,2,3,0,0}. Why does only the last digit in the array get replaced? Doesn't the [value] get replaced each time a new number is assigned?

```
int []  = {4, 2, 3, 0, 1};
int count =0;
int value = arr[0];

while (arr[value] > 0){
count++;
arr[value] = arr[ arr[value] ];
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your iterator (denoted as value) is initialized with 4 and is never changed again.
4 is the fifth element in the array.
Take a look at line 3

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `value` one time, with the line below. It will always be set to `4` since that's the value at `arr[0]`.

```
int value = arr[0];
```

Here is a minor rewrite of your loop to illustrate what it's doing. Instead of `arr[value]`, I just replaced it with `4`:

```
int[] arr = {4, 2, 3, 0, 1};
while (arr[4] > 0) {
    arr[4] = arr[arr[4]];
}
```